# What's the best way to store the bible in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

What I'm looking for is a breakdown of table names w/ corresponding fields/types.

The bible I want to store will be in English and needs to support the following:

- Books
- Chapters
- Section Titles (can show up within verses and in-between verses)
- Smallcaps Text
- Red Letter Text
- Verse Numbers
- Footnotes (can show up within verses and within section titles) (may optionally reference another verse)
- Cross-references (essentially a footnote that only references another verse and doesn't add any commentary)
- Anything else I'm forgetting

Comment: SQL is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Sounds more like you need a decent word processor or desktop publishing system.

Comment: What's the best way to do it for the web then?

Comment: @Stephanie: That is not helpful at all.  It's easy to see examples of what I want by searching Google, but it isn't possible to see how those bible websites store and interact with the bible on the backend.

Comment: Which is why it's a comment and not an answer. But you're absolutely correct. I apologize. I shouldn't get frustrated with design questions about widely covered topics. Everyone has a right to pursue any avenue of development.... and get help. Although, as other people point out to "questions" like this, your post is more a 'work order' than a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, you might consider using a "Bible SDK" such as [AV Bible](http://www.avbible.net/), which stores text, formatting, verse numbers, etc. in an open, custom binary format.

I think they have everything you've listed except cross-references.

Comment: How might I use something like this for the web?  Would I have to make my own class in a server-side language that would be able to query such a binary file?  Or should some sort of different solution be used for the web?

Comment: @John: I haven't looked at AV Bible in any depth yet.  The [SDK page](http://www.avbible.net/pageSDK/pageSDK.html) offers example C++ and C# code; I suspect that they only offer the actual binary file, so most likely you either drop in their example C# code if you're using a .NET server, or you generally copy the C# class(es) to a PHP or Ruby (or whatever) class.  In either case, the binary file should be sufficient (and if you wanted a different translation, that format should be an excellent starting point).

Comment: Regretfully, the www.avbible.net URL being referred to here is longer functional.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another collection / example for you:

https://github.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases

Here you will see SQL, XML, CSV, and JSON. Of special note is the cross-reference table (quite extensive and amazing) and a simple verse-id system for fast queries.

EDIT: Notice the ids of the tables are book-chapter-verse combinations, always unique.

Comment: found this to be A reliable source so far, will update if I find issues - other reliable sources exist such as crosswire sword (use https://github.com/danday74/sword-to-json to convert to JSON) and opensong and biblehub - all other sources I've found so far contain errors in their content - spent a lot of time filtering through all the available sources - APIs are often reliable but I prefer not to rely on a web service

Answer (score 13):

SQL is the BEST way to store this. Considering your requirement we can split them into two major parts

1. Information that's dependent on individual version

   - Small caps
   - Red letter print
2. Information that isn't dependent on individual version

   - Book, Chapter, Verse numbers
   - Section title
   - Foot notes (??????)
   - Cross Reference
   - Commentary

For various reasons I prefer to store the whole bible project into one SINGLE table, Yes call it as `bible`

For your visual here is my screen I have stored nearly 15 versions of bible in single table. Luckily the different version names are just kept as column wide. When you add more version in future your table grows horizontally which is okay thus the # of rows remain constant(31102). Also, I will request you to realize the convenience of keeping the combination of ('Book, Chapter, Verse') as the PRIMARY key because in most situations that's the look-up way.

[image]

That said here is my recommended table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bible` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, --Global unique number or verse
  `book` varchar(25) NOT NULL,  --Book, chapter, verse is the combined primary key
  `chapter` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `verse` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section_title` varchar(250)  NOT NULL, -- Section title, A section starts from this verse and spans across following verses until it finds a non-empty next section_title
  `foot_note` varchar(1000)  NOT NULL,  -- Store foot notes here
  `cross_reference` int(11) NOT NULL, -- Integer/Array of integers, Just store `id`s of related verses 
  `commentary` text  NOT NULL, -- Commentary, Keep adding more columns based on commentaries by difference authors
  `AMP` text  NOT NULL, -- Keep, keep, keep adding columns and good luck with future expansion
  `ASV` text  NOT NULL,
  `BENG` text  NOT NULL,
  `CEV` text  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book`,`chapter`,`verse`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

*Oh, What about the Small caps and Red letters?*

Well, Small caps & Red letters you can store in version columns using HTML or appropriate formats. In the interface you can strip them off based on user's choice whether he requires red letter or small caps.

For reference, you can download the SQLs from below and customize in your way

[Bibles in SQL format](https://mega.nz/#!fNVGUQ7Q!yXWgj1bJoJkJ_v_D4r3qNzD2JFWBeWtSKDPsC93nwgs)

Comment: The linked site is down.  Anyone know of any mirrors?

Comment: +1 for a concise answer.  It's also the way I do it, except different bibles in different tables.  I hadn't thought of merging them all.  Except for my KJV, for example, I have `book,chapter,verse,contents,in-red` - The `in-red` is the formatted version of `contents` which I select via COALESCE(`in-red`,`contents`) so it picks the one that has data.

Comment: @nehemiah, it looks like the NIV version in the link is the 1984 version, which is actually what I was looking for! May I ask where these came from? How did you get them? thx :)

Comment: @drooh I would have scraped from place like biblegateway, or biblehub which I forgot. Since you mentioned it's 1984 NIV version, can you give some example verses to distinguish how it differs from modern versions. That will help me to recall which place I got it from.

Comment: I'm happy to see the archive you link to above has the NLT version.

I wonder if there would be any issues with using the NLT version in a project? My understanding is that NLT is copyrighted by Tyndale.

Comment: This is a good idea as long as you stick on to English versions of the Bible. There are language such as my mother tongue Malayalam, where a couple of verses are not where the English ones are, and a couple of chapters do not have the same number of verses. In that case you'd have to have different databases I guess

Comment: Also, the above link is broken. Please look into it

Comment: They were take, I guess NIV is coming after for copyright, probably I should leave with a scraping script and people can create .sql at their will and risk.

Answer (score 3):

I also found http://www.lyricue.org/downloads/ that includes several bible translations in mysql format.

Comment: where are the bible downloads, cant see them anywhere - thanks for link btw

Comment: You will have to use the Wayback Machine, https://web.archive.org/web/20160508194912/http://www.lyricue.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

Everything WernerCD's answer, but store the verseText as xml so you can add formatting tags like `<red>e.g. Red Text</red>` and use the tags to format it in your application

Answer (score 2):

This repository contains entire Bible given in sql.

https://github.com/godlytalias/Bible-Database

Comment: interesting link but after researching this I found the data to contain corruptions - found https://github.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases to be more reliable

Comment: Yes, @scrollmapper has better databases. I have used them for my web app as well: http://aaronjs.pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score 1):

Mark Rushakoff's answer is probably the best for you specific need. However more generally if need to store content that either has data within the content or if you need to store data about the content a [Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) is typically used. You can build your own (which WernerCD's answer had a table structure for) or use a [CMS product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems). The list here shows the wide variety of technologies used (around 30 in this list use MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

expanding the DB horizontally isn't very efficient with the potential of having very large tables and complex updates.  so id, book, chapter, verse, V1, V2, V3, V4... Vn just seems to be looking at the problem like a spreadsheet rather than taking advantage of what a DB has to offer.

the references are static (book, chapter, verse) so they can be populated in one table with an id and with that you have the framework of the entire bible.  the verse content can potentially have hundreds of versions so it would be better stored in its own table and linked with a foreign key to identifying the references.  the structure would be primary_id, foreign_id, version, content.

now the content just fills in as needed and there is no need to have thousands of empty fields that in the future you have to go back and fill in or needing to expand the table and backfill all the existing data every time you add a new version. just fill in the verses as you get them which works better I think if you building it yourself.

This also makes sense as some versions only have the NT or some verses that they think were added later aren't available so there is no need to have empty fields you just have the data and it links to the verse reference.  "version" can also be a foreign key to identify more information in the version like a publishing date or long/short name (ie. "NIV", "New International Version") This also works well when using more than one revision of a translation like the 1984 NIV vs 2011 NIV.  Both can be identified as "NIV" but differ in content so the version_id can link another table with expanded information about the version it's using.  Once that data is in and linked properly you can display it however you wish for example combining the publishing date/short version name making a name like "NIV1984" or have a separate column unique for a display name.

I'm not sure how red letter or footnotes could be displayed and I know sites like biblegateway have this as a toggle switch so it's nice to have the option to sort it like this.  with red letters, this could be a special static identifier directly in the verse content that is parsed out later as a CSS identifier.  It could be its own foreign table too but since it is so little a delimiter would be really easy.  It really depends what you're using the data for and if you wanted to do queries for the red letters then it would be best as a foreign table (fast) rather then search the db for the delimiter (slow)

with footnotes, since it depends on unique content it would be best stored in its own table.  how it is identified and placed in the content could use static reference points within the content like x number of characters in or x number of words in and then linked with the content using a foreign key again.  So the footnote table could be something like primary_id, foreign_id, reference, footnote and an example of the data could be 2304, 452, 64, "some manuscripts don't include this".  Primary key would be 2304, the foreign key that links to the content table is 452, the footnote is placed 64 characters in, and the footnote is "some manuscripts don't include this" As for the incrementing footnote like A, B, C or 1, 2, 3 all of this can be dynamically generated.  If it's important to be a static letter/number then you might want to include it in the data but I would rather have good data that allows this automatically then list it as static data.

here's the hint, Don't add hundreds of columns... that would just a headache and it's spreadsheet thinking.  it's better to work through the perfect queries to link tables with the right content.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to split the verse_number column into verse_start and verse_end. As example, the 1 Chronicles 6:78 in an Ilocano Bible is merged with verse 79. Therefore, the database must be able to handle a Single verse with 1 Chronicles 6:78-79 as reference. Posting the link for reference. https://ebible.org/study/?w1=bible&t1=local%3Ailoulb&v1=R16_78

As discussed, verse number (start and end) may be Bible version specific. It all depends on the Bible versions you are working on.