# Best way to parse the Bible in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am creating an Android app that needs to access the Bible. I want it to be offline, so I prefer not to use one of the internet APIs. After reading this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687862/whats-the-best-way-to-store-the-bible-in-sql) post, I decided to store the text locally as XML, like this

```
<bible>
<b n="Genesis">
<c n="1">
<v n="1">In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.</v>
```

My problem is that the file is almost 34,000 lines long (4.4 MB) and it takes a LONG time (a few minutes) to parse the entire text.

Right now I'm using the XmlPullParser, like this

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

InputStream iStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bible);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
xpp.setInput(reader);

int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
    // do something here
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

**Is there a better way to store and/or access the bible locally on Android?**

I've considered storing it as multiple XML files to parse it faster (a separate file for each book) but would prefer not to if possible.

I am open to any suggestions, including storing the text as something other than XML.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at And Bible(http://code.google.com/p/and-bible) which uses the JSword library to parse, search Bible documents.  JSword (http://www.crosswire.org/jsword) uses XML and Lucene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) as a "starting place" - that is, *why not*? (Well, really, an existing library / book reader / well established file schema would even better, but barring that :-)

SQLite has very efficient "on disk" access - e.g. no need to "parse" to memory or read an entire file - and it supports efficient seeks over indices (e.g. looking up a specific verse or getting chapters 2 through 12 in Exodus). I would expect both the SQLite database and the original XML file to have a comparable file size (assuming the XML is UTF-8 encoded).

Then make a program/function to "load" the XML into the appropriate schema in the SQLite database - this can be done ahead of time (e.g. on a PC and then distribute the pre-populate SQLite database files) or the first time said XML is loaded on the client. This can be effectively the same reading code as it is now .. just replace "do something" with "update database".

I would avoid a splitting-of-files approach unless there is a particularly good reason for it - it will make it faster to find a specific chapter/verse, but it doesn't really "solve the problem". Since it's using a sequential reader and not a full DOM it won't necessarily result in less memory - it will just limit the garbage "read over" (and then discarded) while seeking. But then again, *why not* SQLite?

Answer (score 5):

**-** First of all **Parse** the `XML` using `SAX, DOM, or Pull Parser`, Or you can try some awesome Libraries like `JAXP and JAXB or the infamous Castor`.

**-** Secondly you can store the Bible locally into `SQLite` DataBase, As SQLite is merely a **single file WITHOUT any Server**, it works quite faster. It can be as small as 250K in size.

**/////////////////// Edited Part  ///////////////////////////////**

**-** Its always better to keep the **UI work on UI Thread, and Non-UI work on Non-UI thread**, but that became a **LAW** with the arrival of `HONEYCOMB` version of Android.

**-** So you can either use the `Thread along with Handler`, or choose to use the easier option provided by Android know as **PainLess Threading**, its `AsyncTask`

**-** Using the above will keep your `UI` **responsive** while you do the processor heavy work at the background.

Comment: +1 In addition to this, I would recommend doing these tasks in an `AsyncTask`. It can be run concurrently on first run, potentially while asking the user for settings or showing some kind of splash/loading screen.

Comment: @Eric yes you are absolutely right..... I have edited my answer to add the details...thanks for suggesting a good point...+1 to u actually

Answer (score 1):

My advise would be to use something else than XML. Note that I *don't* have anything against XML in general; just want make that clear, since there are quite a few people out there who feel XML is not good for *anything at all*.

Here are some of the anticipated consequences of using XML in this case:

**Lookup times**

It would make jumping to specific positions in your text *always* expensive. XML would offer you two ways to do it:

1. Read the entire document in a streaming way until you hit the fragment that you were looking for. Very slow.
2. Read the entire document into an in-memory data structure, which would allow you to create an in memory index from some sort of location identifier to the actual text fragment.  Very expensive in terms of memory consumption.

**Compactness**

Turning the entire bible into an XML file would make it *HUGE*. Of course there solutions such as [Fast Infoset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Infoset) and [Efficient XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/EXI/) (both binary encodings of [Infoset](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/), the data model behind XML). That would help a little, but perhaps not a lot. Gzip would probably reduce to approx. 1/3 of the original size, which again would help, but it would still be big.

**What to do instead?**

My advise would be to consider a binary encoding of your bible text; one that is optimized for fast lookups. Like, having an index *inside* the file, mapping the location (a verse) to the offset where that actual text fragment starts. And if you do it properly, there is even the bonus of having something that is way more compact than XML.

**Harder?**

It sounds much harder, but in reality, it might not. You might also consider looking at [Preon](http://preon.github.com/), since Preon has been used on Android as well, and allows you to declaratively map an in memory data structure into its binary encoded representation. The framework *itself* will figure out if there is an opportunity to load data lazily, from the input file.